# Drupal maintain rejected user list and authenticate from among

Tags: drupal

Im developing a drupal website with multistep approval of users ,after

registration the admin rejects a user an email is sent to the user and the user

is deleted from drupal user table .

I want to perform a action where in after a user is rejected he will be kept in

a new table with the username and email .

If the same user contacts admin,the admin will remove the user from the rejected

users list ,because during registration for second time it should also check for

the user in the rejected user list.

Is i t something that is possible in Drupal?

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible except the wooden stove! Show some effort, try something on your own and when you get stuck ask.

There's no out of box solution for this (that I know about it), but what I would do is make custom content type for storing users and use hook functions to insert/check existence of rejected users.

hook that is called when user is deleted:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_delete/7.x

hook that is called when node (rejected user) is deleted
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7.x

But maybe your admin can just disable user instead of deleting it as first step - that way wouldn't need that extra table at all.